Cannot catch ListProfileObjects on Event Bridge
I was looking to get connect customer profile ID when the agent click the Customer Profile.
I was looking at cloudtrail and I see that it was being log on ListProfileObjects Event.
    "eventSource": "profile.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "ListProfileObjects",
    "awsRegion": "ap-southeast-2",
    "sourceIPAddress": "connect.amazonaws.com",
    "userAgent": "connect.amazonaws.com",
    "requestParameters": {
        "ProfileId": "xxxx",
        "max-results": "100",
        "DomainName": "amazon-connect-xxx-client",
        "ObjectTypeName": "_case"
    },

I was trying to use the EventBridge rule since but no luck on my end it was not triggering. Anyone can help me on this?
{
  "source": ["aws.profile"],
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["profile.amazonaws.com"],
    "eventName": ["ListProfileObjects"]
  }
}

I already tried all pattern even leaving the patter to source only but ListProfileObject is not showing.
I was expecting a return of the ListProfileObject event return.
